Caching local files in coil
caching Images from Internet is working in coil. Is it possible to cache thumbnails of local files?
I am working on a file manager app. every time lazycolumn requests the thumbnail, coil-videoframedecoder creates a new bitmap. its taking some time. what is the best way to save the processed bitmap and load it instead of creating new one?

Name a few ways. After that we will speak.

sorry i'm a beginner. can you suggest one? I mainly want to know is it possible with coil? otherwise i have to use a linkedhashmap or something like manually

That is not the way it goes here. You should tell which problem you have caching a bitmap. Further we know too little. For instance how long should the cache be valid? At next program start too?. Or only while scrolling up and down one directory.

I do not know coil so i dont know which problems you see making a cache.

But a cache should not be needed for thumbnails from image files. And then i dont know how much time it takes to make a bitmap of a video. Is it much more?

How is the user of your app aware that it takes some time to create that bitmap? Is your app unresponsive then?

i want thumbnails stored permenantly on device.  for images or album art there is no delay. coil-video extension taking too much time for creating a bitmap from video. So there is a delay to appear the thumbnail while scrolling. I want this image save on disk and next time load this image without processing video again

You did not answer my questions. For instance how much more time does it take to build a bitmap from a video file then from an image file.

almost 0.5 second need for video. for images, it appear instantly

Nobody will complain about half a second as long as your app is responsive and scrolling is not stopped by it. If scrolling is fluent.

still I didn't get answer for my question.  anyway thanks.

You better start a new post asking how to save a bitmap to file using coil.

i found in coil github issues that this is not possible with coil but glide can. so i am going to test glide
